# PHP Big characteristic double cast issue

Tags: php

I have value:

```
$val = 1349882.75475186
$d = (double)1349882.75475186 
var_dump($d) # result: 1349882.7547519
```

this issue is only for big characteristic

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic

 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Try writing `1349822.75475186` in binary. When you're done, let me know!

Comment: I used strings and BC Math http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php